# Как задать условие в jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

В общем есть несколько сайтов к которым привязан один js файл, у каждого сайта свой класс у body,
так вот, как задать условие в jquery что бы это условие принималось ко всем body кроме определенного body. Я новичек, прошу помочь, а не кидаться помидорами))

```js
if ($("body") != $(".site-one")) {
    $(function() {
        $(".callback-fixed-btn").click(function() {
            $("#callBackFormSlide").removeClass("hideFixed");
        })
    });

    $(function() {
        $(".cb-close").click(function() {
            $("#callBackFormSlide").toggleClass("hideFixed");
        })
    });

    $(function() {
        $(".subscription__call").click(function() {
            $(".subscription").toggleClass("ShowSubscribe");
        })
    });

    $(function() {
        $(".close").click(function() {
            $(".subscription").removeClass("ShowSubscribe");
        })
    });

    $(function() {
        $(".thanksAction").click(function() {
            var url = "/";
            $(location).attr('href',url);
        })
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

все, нашел! Извиняюсь если потревожил

```js
if ($('body').attr("class") != "site-one") {
    $(function() {
        $(".callback-fixed-btn").click(function() {
            $("#callBackFormSlide").removeClass("hideFixed");
        })
    });

    $(function() {
        $(".cb-close").click(function() {
            $("#callBackFormSlide").toggleClass("hideFixed");
        })
    });

    $(function() {
        $(".subscription__call").click(function() {
            $(".subscription").toggleClass("ShowSubscribe");
        })
    });

    $(function() {
        $(".close").click(function() {
            $(".subscription").removeClass("ShowSubscribe");
        })
    });

    $(function() {
        $(".thanksAction").click(function() {
            var url = "/";
            $(location).attr('href',url);
        })
    });

}
```

Comment: `if (!$('body').hasClass("site-one")) {`

Answer (score 1):

Лучше использовать функцию [not](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$("body").not(".site-one")
```

или селектор [:not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$("body:not('.site-one')")
```